# HTML page layout disturbed in IE with auto margin

Tags: html, css, utf-8, multilingual

I have a website with multi-language my page encoding is `utf-8`, when i use encoding `utf-8` it shows all languages but page goes to left and auto margin does not work. when i turn off `utf-8` then it shows page in middle (that i want) but all languages turns into boxes.

here is my page encoding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I have open pages in text editor and saved as with encoding `utf-8`

when i save as encoding `ANSI` its layout works fine like i mention below and for `utf-8` not

How can I solve that issue?

This issue comes in IE i am using IE9

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same issues with just using:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Yes. it shows same result. here you can see screen shoot [link] (http://dummyagent.com/1.JPG) and without utf-8 [link] (http://dummyagent.com/2.JPG) . not just above code insertion works, i open this file in note pad and then save as in utf-8 then it show other languages as in 1.JPG

Comment: Check that you have a valid doctype. What is the first line of your html?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>